# Plot a line along a constant latitude in Basemap, Python when using a conic projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, matplotlib-basemap

I would like to draw a line connecting two points of *equal latitude* on a `basemap` instance, using a *conical* map projection (i.e. where latitudes are **not** straight lines).

Irrespective of whether I use `m.drawgreatcircle` or `m.plot`, the resulting line is a **straight** (-I think...?) line between the two points, as opposed to a line that goes along a *constant latitude*. Does anybody know how to solve this problem? Some example code and the resulting image is below. I would dearly love that yellow dashed line to run along the 55N line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

#set up the map
m = Basemap(resolution='l',area_thresh=1000.,projection='lcc',\
        lat_1=50.,lat_2=60,lat_0=57.5,lon_0=-92.5,\
        width=6000000,height=4500000)


#add some basic map features
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-155,-5,10),\
       labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=8,linewidth=0.5)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(30,85,5),\
       labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=8,linewidth=0.5)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
m.drawcountries(linewidth=1)
m.drawstates(linewidth=0.3)

#plot some topography data
m.etopo()

#draw a line between two points of the same latitude
m.drawgreatcircle(-120,55,-65,55,linewidth=1.5,\
       color='yellow',linestyle='--')
```

[image: I want the yellow dashed line to run along the line of latitude!]

Apologies if I am missing something extremely simple...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawgreatcicle` is apparently not working correctly on a `lcc` projection map.

You can always just create a line yourself instead of relying on this helper function. To this end, create coordinates along the line, project them and call `plot`.

```
lon = np.linspace(-120,-65)
lat = np.linspace(55,55)
x,y = m(lon,lat)
m.plot(x,y, linewidth=1.5, color='yellow',linestyle='--')
```

[image]